# Prevent duplicate data in a table with more than 20000 records

Tags: php, mysql

everyday i add almost 5000 new records in mysql and i want to prevent insert duplicate row in table,i think i should check all of the bank befor any insert operation,is it suitable?
Or there is any better way to do that??
thanks in advance

Comment: Yes in MySQL make a group of columns `UNIQUE`

Comment: use on duplicated update ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: thats right,but i doesn't spend all the source RAM CPU ...,does it????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good choice to prevent the data model beeing corrupted by software by applying a unique index to the field attributes which must not be duplicatable.

It's even better to ask the database for duplicate candidates before inserting data.

The best is, to have both combined. The security on the database model and the question for duplicates in the software layer because a) error handling is much more expensive than querying and b) the constraint protects the data from human failure.

mysql supports unique indexes with the CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement.

e.g: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_FOO ON BAR(X,Y,Z);

creates a unique index on table BAR. This index will also be used when running the query for duplicates - speeds up the processing very much.

See [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks gorefest,i'm in lack of source!sometimes i prefer to have duplicate data instead of checking all table,i think this operation needs lots of source,but ...?

Comment: if you know about the columns which prevent duplicates, all you need is the index. An INSERT will cause the database block the operation with a unique index violation then. If you have few duplicates, this is the easiest way to prevent dupes. If you have many duplicate candidates, you should query for the duplicate values first to prevent a larger error handling overhead. This is easily achievable by SELECTing for the indexed columns.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a data integrity issue, you want the database to enforce the rules (if possible).  In your case, you do this with a unique index or unique constraint, which are two names for the same thing.  Here is sample syntax:

```
create unique index idx_table_col1_col2 on table(col1, col2)
```

You want to do this in the database, for three reasons:

- You want the database to *know* that that column is unique.
- You do not want a multi-threaded application to "accidentally" insert duplicate values.
- You do not want to put such important checks into the application, where they might "accidentally" be removed.

MySQL then has very useful constructs to deal with duplicates, in particular, `insert . . . on duplicate key update`, `insert ignore`, and `replace`.

When you run SQL queries from your application, you should be checking for errors anyway, so catching duplicate key errors should be no additional burden on the application.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, any column that needs to be unique you can use the `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName 
(id SERIAL, someUniqueColumnName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE);
```

See the MySQL Documentation [for adding uniqueness to existing columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table-examples.html).

You need to decide what constitutes a duplicate in your table, because uniqueness is not always restricted to a single column. For instance, in a table where you store users with a corresponding id for something else, then it may be both combined which have to be unique. For that you can have `PRIMARY KEY` which uses two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableName (
    id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    pictureId BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    someOtherColumn VARCHAR(12),
    PRIMARY KEY(id, pictureId));
```